# Power BI - Total of Averages Across Multiple Hierarchy Levels

Tags: powerbi, dax, hierarchy

I'm looking for a DAX expression capable of loading the Total of Averages for each level in a hierarchy. My current code can be found below:

```
VAR FiscalDate = CALCULATE(IF(HASONEVALUE(SortOrder_Date[Date]), AVERAGE('Financial Summary Detail'[TransactionAmount]), SUMX(VALUES(SortOrder_Date[Date]), CALCULATE(AVERAGE('Financial Summary Detail'[TransactionAmount]),'Financial Summary Detail'[ValidLineFlag]=1,'Financial Summary Line Type'[FinancialSummaryLineTypeId]=3))))
VAR FiscalWeek = CALCULATE(IF(HASONEVALUE(SortOrder_FiscalWeek[Fiscal Week]), AVERAGE('Financial Summary Detail'[TransactionAmount]), SUMX(VALUES(SortOrder_FiscalWeek[Fiscal Week]), CALCULATE(AVERAGE('Financial Summary Detail'[TransactionAmount]),'Financial Summary Detail'[ValidLineFlag]=1,'Financial Summary Line Type'[FinancialSummaryLineTypeId]=3))))
VAR FiscalPeriod = CALCULATE(IF(HASONEVALUE(SortOrder_FiscalPeriod[Fiscal Period]), AVERAGE('Financial Summary Detail'[TransactionAmount]), SUMX(VALUES(SortOrder_FiscalPeriod[Fiscal Period]), CALCULATE(AVERAGE('Financial Summary Detail'[TransactionAmount]),'Financial Summary Detail'[ValidLineFlag]=1,'Financial Summary Line Type'[FinancialSummaryLineTypeId]=3))))
VAR FiscalQuarter = CALCULATE(IF(HASONEVALUE(SortOrder_FiscalQuarter[Fiscal Quarter]), AVERAGE('Financial Summary Detail'[TransactionAmount]), SUMX(VALUES(SortOrder_FiscalQuarter[Fiscal Quarter]), CALCULATE(AVERAGE('Financial Summary Detail'[TransactionAmount]),'Financial Summary Detail'[ValidLineFlag]=1,'Financial Summary Line Type'[FinancialSummaryLineTypeId]=3))))
VAR FiscalYear = CALCULATE(IF(HASONEVALUE(SortOrder_FiscalYear[Fiscal Year]), AVERAGE('Financial Summary Detail'[TransactionAmount]), SUMX(VALUES(SortOrder_FiscalYear[Fiscal Year]), CALCULATE(AVERAGE('Financial Summary Detail'[TransactionAmount]),'Financial Summary Detail'[ValidLineFlag]=1,'Financial Summary Line Type'[FinancialSummaryLineTypeId]=3))))

RETURN

SWITCH(
    TRUE()
        , ISINSCOPE(SortOrder_Date[Date]), FiscalDate
        , ISINSCOPE(SortOrder_FiscalWeek[Fiscal Week]), FiscalWeek
        , ISINSCOPE(SortOrder_FiscalPeriod[Fiscal Period]), FiscalPeriod
        , ISINSCOPE(SortOrder_FiscalQuarter[Fiscal Quarter]), FiscalQuarter
        , ISINSCOPE(SortOrder_FiscalYear[Fiscal Year]), FiscalYear
)
```

Comment: I think you are missing alot of informantion here... is it working?Returning an error? What is the expected outcome? Some sample data helps and outcome goes a long way.

Comment: I'd have to prepare some dummy data but basically I'm getting the averages without a sum with the above dax. I'm hoping someone has more of a general formula they've used in the past.

Comment: Provide sample data with your expected output from them.